# Passing setState hook as prop to a component using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am quite new to TypeScript and I can't figure out how to pass the setState hook to my child component.

I declared my State variable `expenseState` inside `App.tsx` and I'm trying to pass it along with the SetStateAction `setExpenseState`.

**App.tsx**

```
type ExpensesType = {
    expenseList: Expense[];
    filteredYear?: number;
}

const expenses: Expense[] = [
    { id: 'e01', title: 'Car Insurance', amount: 300.12, date: new Date(2022, 1, 18)},
    { id: 'e02', title: 'Car Insurance 1', amount: 300.12, date: new Date(2022, 1, 18)},
  ]; 

const [expenseState, setExpenseState] = useState<ExpensesType>({
    expenseList: expenses,
  });

return (
   <Expenses expenseState={expenseState} setExpenseState={setExpenseState} />
);
```

**Expenses.tsx**

```
type ExpensesProps = {
    expenseState: ExpensesType;
    setExpenseState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<ExpensesType>>;
}

const Expenses = (props: ExpensesProps) => {

    
}
```

How can I call and use the `setExpenseState` hook?

***Example***

```
props.setExpenseState({
   expenseList: something     
});
```

Comment: `expenseState` is an array. What you are trying to update, or rather, what are you wanting to update it with? Well, actually, NM, you declared it an array of `Expense` type, but then initialize it to an object with an `expenseList` property. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited my post.  I declared `expenseState` as `expensesType` type.

Comment: Ok, then I suppose the `props.setExpenseState({ expenseList: something });` appears to be correct, assuming `something` is of type `Expense[]`... but the typescript linter would inform you if it wasn't. Is there an issue trying to update your state?

Comment: Ok I got it now. I just wasn't sure if `props.setExpenseState({ expenseList: something });` is the correct way of calling it. Thanks for the help!